# Amazon MQ in shared VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I have a scenario where I am launching a AmazonMQ(Rabbit MQ) broker in shared vpc private subnets with private access, but it fails with the message as `error info: Unable to create endpoints in the VPC to which the specified subnets belong. Please specify subnets associated with a VPC owned by your AWS account.`

I understand that the MQ should be launched in the same owner account as of shared VPC but unfortunately there is no access to the account and also there is no access to create a new VPC in the existing member account.

How to overcome this scenario I couldn't find detailed description around this and expectation is to avoid launching the AWS RabbitMQ in any other VPC other than shared VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Generally VPC endpoints could not be created by VPC participant accounts i.e. not VPC owner accounts. `ActiveMQ` may not have this limitation like `RabbitMQ`. You can look at building `RabbitMQ` in a standalone VPC and use [PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/) to connect the resource to the shared VPC.